# Вернуть список чисел но в обратном порядке

Tags: python

Нужна помощь, есть класс который возвращает список простых чисел:

```
class LowerPrime:
    def __init__(self, number: int):
        self.lower_numbers = []
        self.number = number
        self.it = 1

    def __iter__(self):
        self.it = 1
        return self

    def get_lower_numbers(self):
        self.it += 1
        for lower in self.lower_numbers:
            if self.it % lower == 0:
                return False
        return True

    def __next__(self):
        while self.it < self.number:
            if self.get_lower_numbers():
                self.lower_numbers.append(self.it)
                return self.it
        else:
            raise StopIteration()


lower_prime = LowerPrime(number=11)
lower_prime_it = iter(lower_prime)
print(next(lower_prime_it))  # == 7
print(next(lower_prime_it))  # == 5
print(next(lower_prime_it))  # == 3
print(next(lower_prime_it))  # == 2
```

Но при возврате простого числа, он возвращает простые числа в обратном порядке, нужно например 7, 5, 3, 2 он возвращает 2, 3, 5, 7. Также нужно что бы при наличии наименьшего простого 2 возвращалось raise StopIteration.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Кстати,  по пункту "пишите грамотно" - что означает фраза "Также нужно что бы при наличии наименьшего простого 2 возвращалось raise StopIteration"? При наличилии наименьшего просто 2 ГДЕ?

Comment: У вас, кстати, уже в заголовке есть ответ. Поэтому я ни на секунду не поверю, что вы пытались как-то решать эту проблему

Comment: По вашему алгоритму простые числа генерируются начиная с наименьших. Причем при поиске следующего простого числа используются ранее сгенерированные. Поэтому и выводятся начиная с наименьших. Как вариант - в `__init__` сразу генерируете весь список простых чисел, а в `__next__` просто проходите по нему с конца и возвращаете числа.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По вашему алгоритму простые числа генерируются начиная с наименьших. Причем при поиске следующего простого числа используются ранее сгенерированные. Поэтому и выводятся начиная с наименьших.
Как вариант - в **init** сразу генерируете весь список простых чисел, а в **next** просто проходите по нему с конца и возвращаете числа.

```py
class LowerPrime:
    def __init__(self, number: int):
        self.lower_numbers = []
        self.number = number
        self.it = 1
        while self.it < self.number-1:
            self.it += 2 # вынесено сюда из функции get_lower_numbers()
            if self.get_lower_numbers():
                self.lower_numbers.append(self.it)
#        self.lower_numbers = self.lower_numbers[::-1] # реверс списка - можно не делать
#        print(self.lower_numbers) # посмотреть сгенерированный список
```

Ещё, на мой взгляд увеличение итератора `self.it` должно быть не в методе `get_lower_numbers()`, а в цикле генерации параметров.
Остается только в методе `__next__()` пройти по списку и выдать все числа по одному.
Ещё маленькая оптимизация - проверять нужно только нечетные числа (т.к. четные делятся на 2). Поэтому итератор нужно увеличивать не на 1, а на 2 - тогда будут проверяться числа 3,5,7,9 ...

Comment: Добавлю, что есть замечательный алгоритм [Решето Эратосфена](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE_%D0%AD%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0), которые работает за `O(n*log(log(n)))`, который идеально подходит для решении данной задачи.